# Oracle Apex with SiteMinder

Tags: single-sign-on, oracle-apex, reverse-proxy, siteminder

I am trying to integrate Oracle Apex with SSO provided by CA Siteminder. 
The Apache that ships with Apex is not compatible with the Siteminder version we have in our organisation. 
I need to make sure that session management works and also to read some items from the environment variables, which are  set by SiteMinder after successful login, like the employee number.
Is there a way through reverse_proxy that allows forwarding dynamically set enviroment variables?

TIA,
Saurabh

tl;dr
We have an Apex instance in which I want to implement Siteminder SSO. The apache that comes with Apex is binary incompatiple with Siteminder :-( . Is there a way through reverse_proxy (or any other) , so that I can authenticate on an external apache and then redirect to Apex, with some environment variables?

Comment: I think you may have more success asking this on the [OTN apex forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=137). Don't forget to clarify your setup a bit more, such as if you are using apex listener.